# Showing and hiding the action bar in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a project with one activity and several fragments. The fragments are replaced from the activity. The main menu fragment should not have action bar, but the action bar should persist on all other fragments. Also the default back button should work. I am using this code: *getActivity().getActionBar().hide();* to hide the actionbar and

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.show();
```

to show it.

But what confuses me most is the theme. Which theme should i use in order to have light background and should i define all properties like textColor, background when extending a theme like ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar? This theme made a mess to the UI.
What is the best way to do all this?

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to declare all properties, why dont u use the default themes. This is example how i have do it:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ProjActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="ProjActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ProjActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="ProjActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>
```

Another way that i prefer more is this one:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 </style>
 <style name="AppTheme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <!-- add custom atribute if you want -->
 </style>
```

Comment: I pasted the xml code and changed the names of the color variables and ran the application. But calling getActivity().getActionBar().hide(); from the MainMenuFragment.java throws NullPointerException. The debugger shows that the action bar is null. Previously i had the same problem when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

Comment: Does the MainActivity have to extend the Activity class or ActionBarActivity class?

Comment: Ok, if you use Theme.AppCompat (its better than Theme.Holo so keep using it) you need to call:  Android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); Try with this code

Comment: That works: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();